# How Do I Create Gradient Long Shadow For App Icon As Per Material Design Guidelines In VectorDrawables?

Tags: android, icons, adobe-illustrator, android-vectordrawable, adaptive-icon

Actually, I am Developing An Android App. The Issue Is About Exporting Icon With Gradients In VectorDrawables. I Draw My Icons Using Adobe Illustrator And I export them To Android Studio' Asset Studio.

> As Per Material Design Guidelines, The Shadow Of An Object Should Be Radial Gradual Gradient Where 1st Slider Is At 32% Location And Opacity Is 15%. 2nd Slider Is at 62% Location with 2% Opacity. And The Last Slider Is At 100 % With Completely Transparent Color With 45° Angle

I have created The Icon In Adobe Illustrator and looks perfectly and follows everything as per material design.
But When I export them to Android Studio, The Image Is Heavily Altered As Vector Drawables Doesn't Support Gradients Fully Yet. Gradients in VectorDrawables is supported from Android 7.0 + devices.
Another Issue Is That Google Says That an object with elevation should show long shadow with 45° (Gradient-based). But on the other side, They do not support gradients fully. How can I extend gradient app icon to devices which are below 7.0.

P.s. I export the Illustrator File To support Adaptive Icon.
Please, someone, guide me to achieve that gradient shadow In VectorDrawables so that they will look similar to legacy icons

Answer (score 4):

Instead of including the shadow's gradient in illustrator, you can manually add it to the path in the vector xml file:

```
<path 
    android:pathData="...">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient
          android:type="radial"
          android:centerX="54"
          android:centerY="54"
          android:gradientRadius="76.37">
        <!-- 15% black from center to 32% stop -->
        <item android:offset="0.0" android:color="#26000000" />
        <item android:offset="0.32" android:color="#26000000" />
        <!-- 2% black at 62% stop -->
        <item android:offset="0.62" android:color="#05000000" />
        <!-- fade to transparent -->
        <item android:offset="1.0" android:color="#00000000" />
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
```

For more details https://medium.com/google-developers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e

Note: gradient support was added to VectorDrawables in API 24.